# C# How to save image from an OLE Object stored in a Database

Tags: c#, image, ms-access

It seems that header bytes are stored along with an image when it is embedded into an access database as a OLE Object and they are preventing me from writing the bytes stored to disc as it raises an exception 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'

How do you extract only the image bytes from a OLE Object stored in an access database and then save to disk?

```
photo = ((rs.Fields["photo"].Value == System.DBNull.Value) ? 
    null : (byte[])rs.Fields["photo"].Value)

...

if (photo != null)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(photo);
    Image image = new Bitmap(stream);
    stream.Close();

    image.Save(@"C:\Temp\images\test", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(photo))
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(stream))
{
    image.Save(@"C:\Temp\images\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: @Nicholas Murray, and `using` to properly dispose `IDisposable` resources such as streams and GDI objects like Images.